# How to set background image in android phone

Tags: html, css, background-image

Image was not filled in full screen.
White space was existed top or bottom. Image is short for screen.
Why is this occurred?

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("images1/App_Wall3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;       
}
```

Comment: how is it related to android,are you displaying it in webview?

Comment: Yes we develop web app style mobile app